# Displaying the images using a list of arrays in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am new to JAVAFX and I am creating a card game. I have a problem in displaying the pictures of the card on the screen.

I have card images in one folder in the JAVA Project and I am accessing it. But when I run the program I cannot see any images of the cards on the screen.

Here is my code.

```
     public class Main extends Application 
            { 
                public static void main(String args[]) 
                { 
                    // launch the application 
                    launch(args); 
                }   

                public void start(Stage s) 
                { 

                      TilePane r = new TilePane(); 
                      Scene sc = new Scene(r);
                      List<Image>card = new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    card.add(new Image(getClass().getResource(i+".png").toExternalForm()));
                }

                ImageView view1 = new ImageView(card.get(1));
                ImageView view2 = new ImageView(card.get(2));
                ImageView view3 = new ImageView(card.get(3));


                view1.setImage(card.get(1));
                view2.setImage(card.get(2));
                view3.setImage(card.get(3));
                s.setScene(sc);  
                s.show(); 
                }

            }
```

Comment: You need to actually add the `ImageView`s to the scene graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `ImageViews` to the `TilePane` and the `TilePane` to the `Scene`

```
TilePane r = new TilePane();
r.getChildren().addAll(view1,view2,view3);
Scene sc = new Scene(r);
s.setScene(sc);  
s.show();
```